# WOPI Editing Document

Tags: java, onenote, ms-wopi

I have implemented the putFile endpoint for WOPI client (i.e. Office Online)
When clicking the edit document button, what should be the first request go to WOPI client?

I have called following URL on edit link:

```
POST https://word-edit.officeapps-df.live.com/we/wordviewerframe.aspx?WOPISrc=https://domain/WOPI_IntegrationDemo/wopi/files/Sample_application_content3.docx/
```

But document says that it'll perform a lock request first. What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you're implementing a WOPI host. The URL looks pretty much ok - just make sure the WOPISrc parameter is escaped and that you include `access_token` parameter.

When you click the URL you instruct the WOPI client (OO/OWA) to load a field defined by WOPISrc from WOPI host.

The WOPI client usually tries to acquire a lock (exclusive write access) from WOPI host first. For those purposes you should implement the LOCK operation in your WOPI host according to the [documentation](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/Lock.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you must Add Access token for this 
then you try to word edit it call to 
 1.get file info. Get [Route("files/{name}/")]
 2.post file. Post [Route("files/{name}/")]
  in hear you have to implement response for Lock files Cobalt Request
       var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    if (xWopiOverride == "LOCK" || string.Equals(xWopiOverride, "UNLOCK"))
                    {
                        //for docx, xlsx and pptx
                        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    }
                else if (string.Equals(xWopiOverride, "COBALT"))
                {
                    //cobalt, for docx and pptx

```
                EditSession editSession = EditSessionManager.Instance.GetSession(access_token);
                if (editSession == null)
                {
                    editSession = new FileSession(access_token, fileInfo, matterInfo, dpsUserName, databaseInfo, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, false);
                    EditSessionManager.Instance.AddSession(editSession);
                }

                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                var atomFromByteArray = new AtomFromByteArray(memoryStream.ToArray());

                ProtocolVersion protocolVersion;
                object context;
                var requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
                requestBatch.DeserializeInputFromProtocol(atomFromByteArray, out context, out protocolVersion);
                editSession.ExecuteRequestBatch(requestBatch);

                foreach (var request in requestBatch.Requests)
                {
                    if (request.GetType() == typeof(PutChangesRequest) && request.PartitionId == FilePartitionId.Content)
                    {
                        editSession.Save();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                var responseContent = requestBatch.SerializeOutputToProtocol(protocolVersion, context);
                var correlationId = Request.Headers.GetValues("X-WOPI-CorrelationID").First();

                response.Headers.Add("X-WOPI-CorrelationID", correlationId);
                response.Headers.Add("request-id", correlationId);

                var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContext, transportContent) =>
                {
                    responseContent.CopyTo(outputStream);
                    outputStream.Close();
                });

                response.Content = pushStreamContent;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = responseContent.Length;
            }
            return response;
```